# How to git add Grunt-generated files to my Github repository?

Tags: javascript, git, github, gruntjs, video.js

I see that a lot of projects, e.g., [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js), are now using [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) to build source files.

My problem is that when I `git clone` a project into my repo, run `grunt`, and then `git add/commit/push` some changes to my repo, the Grunt-generated files don't get pushed.

There has to be a simple solution,right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build/compiled files generally don't belong in a repo. You would usually build your application as part of a post-deploy build script, or something similar.

You can control which files are added to a repo with the `.gitignore` file: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

If you really want to commit build files to your repo, check the `.gitignore` file in the root of your application and remove the relevant lines.

Comment: -@badsyntax thanks. But if the project is only one of many and will only rarely change having to build each one every time you deploy your full application seems like unnecessary overhead. Maybe I'm not understand what you mean by "build your application". Might you expand a bit? I'm a solo relatively inexperienced developer so my deploy process is as simple as `git add/commit/push`.

Comment: In the context of this thread, when I say "build your application", I mean running grunt to compile/concat/compress your CSS, Javascript and other assets files for production use. The problem I've found with committing compiled files to the repo is that they cause merge conflicts when other people are working on the team. In any case, here's the problem: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/.gitignore#L2-L3 Remove those lines and you'll be able to commit the build files.

Comment: @badsyntax thank you, I found this very helpful in tidying up my git project